# Multiple jquery datatables with external data - only one will load

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have 2 jquery datatables on the same page and they wont load together

The first table loads but the second table hangs with the 'processing icon' and the server side script to get the data is never called if you look in the network section of developers bar

If i leave the first table on the page but dont load its data the second datatable loads absolutely fine. It is as if I cannot have 2 datatables with server side processing

Here is the code for loading the tables in document ready. As i have said i have confirmed they both load independently

```
       var btable = $('#branchesdt').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
                 "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "branch_name" },
            { "data": "branch_email" },
            { "data": "tel" },
            { "data": "fax" },
            { "data": "address1" },
                        { "data": "address2" },
            { "data": "town" },
            { "data": "city" },
            { "data": "county" },
            { "data": "postcode" },
                        { "data": "country_name" },


             {"data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
                         } 

             ],
             "ajax": "DataTables/branches_dt.php"


    } 

       );


   var etable = $('#employeesdt').DataTable( 


           {

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
                 "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "ajax": "DataTables/employees_dt.php",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "employee_name" },
                        { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "employee_email" },
            { "data": "tel" },
            { "data": "fax" },
            { "data": "mobile" },
                        { "data": "last_contact_date" },
             {"data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
                         } 

             ] 

         }           
    );
```

Thanks in advance for any help you experts can give. It is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Which version of datatables are you using? 
I use version 1.9.4. Try using this version with the following invocation code:

```
dt = $('#branchesdt').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "DataTables/employees_dt.php",
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "aaSorting": [
            [9, "desc"]
        ]});
```

Same for your second table